# How to submit a JavaFX app to MAC App Store?

Tags: java, ios, macos, app-store, javafx-2

I have packaged my `JavaFX` application as a `self-contained application` using simple `JavaFX Deployment` steps on `MAC`. According to link [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on MAC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) , only the last step is remaining which describes [submitting an app to mac store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html#mac_app_store) . But unfortunately links that lead us to help page are redirecting to the same [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/index.html) and that information is not clearly define steps required to submit a `JavaFX` app to `mac store`.  Why I need `XCode` to submit my `Java Application` to `App store`? Do I need go through signing steps again, as my app is already sign with valid certificate issued by `COMODO`?  Can I get any help link which guide me to submit my `JavaFX` app to `MAC app store`?

Steps so far I have done-

```
Create a JAR File
Bundle the JAR File into an App Package
Bundle the JRE with the App Package
Sign the App
```

Now what next to submit a `JavaFX app to MAC App Store`?

Comment: Check this out: http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 2):

The Apple page says you can use Application Loader (`productbuild`) rather than `XCode`.

You must use a certificate from `Apple` for the product signing.

Answer (score 0):

After sign the App, you need package the App to XXXX.pkg like this: "productbuild --component XXXX.app /Applications -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Your Name (Your Team ID)" XXXX.pkg". Then upload XXXX.pkg using "Application Loader" program.